# Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, firefox, proxy, gtk

I keep getting this message when running proxychains and my proxies arent even connected when the browser launches. I am using Ubuntu 22.04. The command below did not work and I have updated, there seems to be no fix on this anywhere on the web not even on ubuntu forum. Please help.

```
sudo snap refresh snapd-desktop-integration --stable
```